# Issues with the BranchCallbackI in C++ with concert

Tags: c++, cplex

I am trying to use the `ILOBRANCHCALLBACK0` macro to call the `getUpPseudoCost()` and `getDownPseudoCost()` methods of the `IloCplex::BranchCallbackI` class in C++ with CPLEX Concert, but it isn't working. Here is my code:

```
ILOBRANCHCALLBACK0(MyBranch){
if (getBranchType() != BranchOnVariable)
cout <<"getUpPseudoCost"<<getUpPseudoCost();
}
...
cplex.use(MyBranch(env));
```

Comment: Probably nothing to do with C++ ?

Comment: Macros usually start with #define keyword

Comment: it is a c++ code with concert CPLEX and i pasted a piece of the code here

Comment: Are you getting a compiler error? Can you edit your question to include the entire error message?

Comment: The error is "no instance of overloaded function "MyBranchI::getUpPseudoCost" matches the argument list". but in CPLEX C++ reference manual i read that "getUpPseudoCost" is in BranchCallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getUpPseudoCost` method requires an argument (see the documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/refcppopl/html/classes/IloCplex_ControlCallbackI.html#method_getUpPseudoCost)); either an `IloIntVar` or an `IloNumVar`. Indeed, the error you shared in the comment section indicates that the `getUpPseudoCost` method exists, but there is no overload that matches your usage.

With the following snippet, I use the `ILOBRANCHCALLBACK1` macro to pass in a variable array and call the `getUpPseudoCost` method:

```
ILOBRANCHCALLBACK1(MyCallback, IloNumVarArray, vars) {
   for (int i = 0; i < vars.getSize(); ++i) {
      cout << "getUpPseudoCost(" << vars[i] << ") = "
           << getUpPseudoCost(vars[i]) << endl;
   }
}
...
IloNumVarArray var(env);
// Build or import the var array, then pass it into the callback.
cplex.use(MyCallback(env, var));
```

Hopefully this gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your reply

Comment: @Mandana: glad to help. If you don't mind, please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so that others can see that the question has been resolved.